# What does `pthread_t chefIds[NUM_CHEFS]` do?

Tags: multithreading, pthreads

`pthread_t chefId` declares a new thread called chefId.

`pthread_t chefId1, chefId2` declares two new threads called chefId1 and chefId2.

What does `pthread_t chefId[NUM_CHEFS]` do?  If `NUM_CHEFS` is equal to two, then my guess is it would do the same exact thing as `pthread_t chefId1, chefId2`.

Am I correct?

Comment: It declares an array of pthread_t objects.  And if you really don't know that, you really need to learn the language you're working in before even thinking about advanced stuff like multithreading.

Comment: This is the regiment my university has setup.  Looks like it will would do the exact same thing as `pthread_t chefId1, chefId2`.  Thanks.